# How can I disable ViewState for dynamically created controls?

Tags: asp.net

I can't seem to be able to disable ViewState for controls that I add to a page dynamically.

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page1" EnableViewState="false" %>
...
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="DropDownPlaceHolder" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_OnClick" Text="Click Me!"  EnableViewState="false"/>
...
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dropDown = new DropDownList();
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

    textBox.EnableViewState = false;

    dropDown.Items.Add("Apple");
    dropDown.Items.Add("Dell");
    dropDown.Items.Add("HP");

    dropDown.AutoPostBack = true;
    dropDown.EnableViewState = false;

    DropDownPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(dropDown);
    DropDownPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(textBox);

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

If I can't disable ViewState on these controls, then I can never programmatically override what a user has entered/selected.

I've tried placing this code in OnInit and Page_Load, but the effect is the same in either location -- ViewState is enabled (the DropDownList maintains selected value and TextBox retains text that was entered).

So, how can I disable ViewState and keep it from populating these controls?

Thanks!

---

Thanks for your response.
Unfortunately, this isn't a workable solution in my situation.

I will be dynamically loading controls based upon a configuration file, and some of those controls will load child controls.

I need to be able to turn the ViewState of controls off individually, without the need to code logic for loading controls in different places (in OnInit vs. LoadComplete
 method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "feature" -- http://support.microsoft.com/?id=316813

Thanks, Microsoft!!

Answer (score 3):

> @This Mat
>
> It seems the post(back) will send the selected value, even if a control has it's viewstate turned off.

Yes.  The post will always send a controls selected/current value.  That's a behavior of HTTP form posting and nothing to do with ASP.NET control/view state.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing there is the [`ControlState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.controlstate.aspx) which was introduced with .Net Framework 2.0.  It is designed to store the absolute minimum information for a control to work, such as the selection in your `DropDownList` and the text in your `TextBox`.  Properties which are only related to appearance, such as `BackColor`, are still persisted within the `ViewState`.

Unlike `ViewState` [you can't turn ControlState off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178577.aspx).

I can only assume this is to avoid confusion from end-users when controls do not do what they are supposed to if they disable `ViewState` without understanding the consequences.

Comment: My understanding was you had to take special steps to enable a control to use ControlState - it doesn't just happen automatically...so perhaps this is not ControlState?

Comment: You need to take special steps to enable a control you are implementing to use ControlState.

If the control which you are using has already been coded to use ControlState you don't have to do anything to enable it's use, it will just happen.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this a bit and found it a little odd. It seems the post(back) will send the selected value, even if a control has it's viewstate turned off.

I did find a good solution around it though, is that if you handle everything after the init and load, you will reload your control after the viewstate has been processed and it will thus, reset the values.

I used the LoadComplete event, example below:

> ```
>  Public Sub Page_In(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _ 
>  Handles Me.LoadComplete
>
>     Dim ddl As New DropDownList()
>     ddl.EnableViewState = False
>     ddl.Items.Add("Hello")
>     ddl.Items.Add("Stackoverflow")
>
>     phTest.Controls.Add(ddl)
>
> End Sub
> ```

Hope this helps.